# Distorted Icons on shortcut sidebar

Tags: icons

I am continuously facing a problem where the icons in sidebar start to get distorted. When I restart my computer - this seems to go away. But it has a tendency to return if I log out and into my user.

Below is a screenshot:

[image]

Here are my specs:

> *-display               
>          description: VGA compatible controller 
>          product: GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] 
>          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation 
>          physical id: 0 
>          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
>          version: a2 
>          width: 64 bits 
>          clock: 33MHz 
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
>          configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0 
>          resources: irq:32 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff 
>   ioport:2000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff   *-display 
>  
>          description: VGA compatible controller 
>          product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller 
>          vendor: Intel Corporation 
>          physical id: 2 
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 
>          version: 12 
>          width: 64 bits 
>          clock: 33MHz 
>          capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list 
>          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
>          resources: irq:31 memory:d3400000-d37fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3130(size=8)

What would be the most effective way to remedy this issue?

Comment: You could start by [edit]ing your question and providing information on the video card  and driver you are using with the command `sudo lshw -C video`. This approach would give us a starting point. Please help us help you!

Comment: You have 2 options. Install the Nvidia drivers as outlined in the tagged duplicate question or connect your monitor to the integrated Intel port. Either approach should address your problem.